# Trapping user input and using as search of Flickr API, need to get button click working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, flickr

I'm trying to get the user to input a search term, and then use that term as a tag to search Flickr's API. I managed to get the basic search working, but something has gone wrong between that and adding the button click event. Can someone put me right? I feel like it's something little that I'm not seeing, I'm pretty new to [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)and [json](/questions/tagged/json).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $("button").click(function() {
      var searchTerm = $("input:text").val();
      var flickrApi = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
      $.getJSON(flickrApi, {
          tags: "searchTerm",
          tagmode: "any",
          format: "json"
        })
        .done(function(data) {
          $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
            $("<img>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
            if (i === 3) {
              return false;
            }
          });
        });
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="search">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
  <div id="images"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hm, it works for me. can you please specify whats going wrong? edit: you should definitly add: $(document).ready(function(){...your code goes here...});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing double quotes in your variable "searchTerm" changing:

```
$.getJSON( flickrApi, {
    tags: "searchTerm",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
})
```

to

```
$.getJSON( flickrApi, {
    tags: searchTerm, // Local variable.
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
})
```

Btw, you need to place your code inside a jQuery function. The jQuery functionality will successfully run when the DOM is ready to interact with HTML tags through jQuery/Javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // jQuery/Javascript code goes here...
});
```

Or the shorthand for `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(function()
{
   // jQuery/Javascript code goes here...
});
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/a29p2qd4/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I haven't had a chance to try it yet as I had to skip ahead to other work, but I'll try it soon.